# Issue after restarting: ORA-6544

Tags: oracle, file, trace

We are running Oracle 12c SE2. We restarted the database instance and are now getting reoccurring error of: ORA-6544 [pevm_peruws_callback-1] [6540]  and it keeps putting out trace files.

One article suggested no TEMP tablespace, but there is a TEMP tablespace. Any other suggestions on how to stop this reoccurring error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ORA-6544 is a "generic-style" error and the second argument normally gives the real error.

ORA-6540 is a PLSQL compilation error, so that would suggest something is trying to compile an invalid PLSQL object and failing.

Look for objects with a status of INVALID, and check those trace files being created - they will most likely have the name of the offending object(s).

When you get errors like this, typically your first port of call should be to log an SR with Support.